# What is the file extension of MySQL Workbench database file?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench

I am new with MySQL Workbench and is wondering what is the file extension of a particular database file that it saves my data into. I have learned that MySQL Workbench saves files into two types of file extensions: .mwb(MySQL Workbench file) and .sql(Structured Query Language file). I had been used to Microsoft Access 2013 and its .accdb file extension, so I was wondering if which of these serves like .accdb extension. Also, I was thinking if I could use that file in a certain connection string like this in VB.NET as was for .accdb:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
```

Comment: Access is a file based DB, MySQL is not.  Storage/extension is generally an implementation detail, but there can be several extensions: opt, frm, ibd, TRG and trn

Comment: SQLite, like Access, saves everything into a singular file. MySQL spreads data across multiple files, often one or more per table.

Comment: MySQL connection string doesn't require file extension - just database name (https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/). Unlike Access/SQLite and similar to other large DBMS, it stores database content in a collation schema instead of a single file.

Answer (score 2):

There's some confusion here, which often happens with MS Access users. MS Access is an application which does not follow the [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model). It uses a local file to store everything.

In a client-server world, however, there is a server holding the data and client tools working with the server to query and modify this data. MySQL Workbench is one of many client tools which can work with a MySQL server.

The file types you mentioned are not holding data like the MS Access db, but have other purposes. An `mwb` file is a model file, which contains data for database design. And an `sql` file is holding SQL commands in pure text. This type is often used for backups (aka. dumps) or to transfer data + structure in text form.

Neither of these files can be used for establishing a connection to a server (nor does it make sense to use them for such a task).

Having said that, it should be clear that there is no MySQL Workbench database file. As a client tool no data is held by MySQL Workbench, but exclusively by the MySQL server.

Comment: Essentially,  there's no way of creating a '.db' file like you would with SQLite.